# iOS - Can you control your app's game center leaderboards?

Tags: ios, game-center

Can you control your app's game center leaderboards? I mean if someone manages to use a glitch and insert a score like 1 million, is it possible to delete those scores?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no, there is no way to administrate Game Center scores as of speaking, however some people have speculated that such feature will be released after iOS 7 (along with encrypted messages to stop cheaters). I guess we will find out tomorrow.